# ember.js - ember-cli: ember-data not available on child view

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm using the latest ember-cli and currently testing it, creating very simple app using ember-data and http-mock for RESTAdapter - **ember generate http-mock api-server**

**Single post get from the API:**

```
http://localhost:4200/api/api-server/posts/1
```

**Result**

```
{"post":
   {
      "id":1,
      "title":"How to write a JavaScript Framework",
      "author":"Tomhuda Katzdale",
      "body":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
   }
}
```

Here are all the relevant codes:

**Adapters**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
   namespace: 'api/api-server'
});
```

**Model**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  author: DS.attr('string'),
  body: DS.attr('string')
});
```

**router.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
   location: EmbercliDataENV.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('application');
  this.resource('posts', function() {
     this.resource('post', { path: ':post_id' });
  });
});

export default Router;
```

**Routes (posts and post) - view and child view**

**posts route**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function() {
      return this.store.find('post');
   }
});
```

**post route**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
     return this.store.find('post', params.post_id);
  }
});
```

**template**

**posts.hbs**

```
<h2>Posts List</h2>

<ul>
  {{#each}}
    <li>
       {{#link-to 'post' this}}{{title}}{{/link-to}} | {{author}} | {{body}}
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
{{outlet}}
```

[image]

**post hbs**

```
<h2>Single Post</h2>

<p>Post title: {{title}}</p>
<p>Post author: {{author}}</p>
<p>Post body: {{body}}</p>
```

***THE PROBLEM: if you look at the screen-cap below, in the chrome ember debugger, the single post model is hooked to the post route but is not printed in the post.hbs***

[image]

Using just the ember starter kit, I got no problem at all with the exact same app.

Thank you for any help, cheers

**UPDATE**

The following is the exact same Ember app coded using the starter kit, host in xampp and using PHP Slim framework  for REST Api. **Working FINE!**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After browsing the Ember.js forum I got the answer there - http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/strange-behavior-w-retrieving-model-from-controller/6155

It seems when using the **Ember generate controller** command, you end up with **Ember.Controller**, not **Ember.ObjectController** or **Ember.ArrayController** lol.

I edit my post controller from: (generate by the Ember generate controller command)

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
});
```

to

```
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
});
```

and now the model is binding :D

Comment: if you need the created controller to be `Object` type, you need to provide the correct option like this, `ember g controller name --type=object`, and if the controller type is `Object` or `Array` only ember will automatically set the *model* property of the corresponding controller from the router's model hook.

Answer (score 0):

try to fix your data, because post is nested in posts, try this:

```
{"post":[
   {
      "id":1,
      "title":"How to write a JavaScript Framework",
      "author":"Tomhuda Katzdale",
      "body":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
   }]
}
```

check within your posts hbs if the data is visible, then post should work fine

Comment: Already try that. Still not working. I don't think the problem is with the data, coz there is data in the model as shown in the screen-cap, bottom right for the child-view post

Comment: good job, if you can answer your own question so people can use it for reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<h2>Posts List</h2>

<ul>
  {{#each}}
    <li>
       {{#link-to 'post' post}}{{title}}{{/link-to}} | {{author}} | {{body}}
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
{{outlet}}
```

1.**instead of 'this' use post**, hope this will fix the issue 
http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/links/#toc_adding-additional-attributes-on-a-link